# ode not working for the stuart landau equation?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, scipy, ode

I am not sure what the issue is in this piece of code. I am trying to solve the following ODE. I solved it with ODEint and for some reason it just gave a flat line answer, which is definitely incorrect. I have corrected the errors in the jacobian and changed the parameters, but nothing is working. I have a version of this code solved in FreeFem++ with the same parameters, so this is surprising.

```py
from scipy.integrate import ode
import numpy as np

A0= [10**-4, 0]
t0 = 0
B0 = 10**-4 + 0j


coeff = np.complex(0.145,-0.088)
coeffr = np.real(coeff)
coeffi = np.imag(coeff)


def f(t,A):
    return [(A[0]**2 + A[1]**2)*(- coeffr*A[0] + coeffi*A[1]), (A[0]**2 + A[1]**2)*(-coeffr*A[0] - coeffi*A[1])]

def jac(t,A):
    return [[ (A[0]**2 + A[1]**2)*(- coeffr) + (2*A[0])*(- coeffr*A[0] + coeffi*A[1]), (A[0]**2 + A[1]**2)*(coeffi) + (2*A[1])*(- coeffr*A[0] + coeffi*A[1])],
            [ (A[0]**2 + A[1]**2)*(-coeffr) + (2*A[0])*(-coeffr*A[1] - coeffi*A[0]) , (A[0]**2 + A[1]**2)*(- coeffi) +  (2*A[1])*(-coeffr*A[0] - coeffi*A[1])]]

def fcomp(t,B):
    return -coeff*abs(B)**2*B

s = ode(fcomp).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf')
s.set_initial_value(B0, t0)
t1 = 100
dt = 0.01

import numpy as np

solution = np.empty((0,100))
time = np.empty((0,100))

while s.successful() and s.t < t1:
    sol = s.integrate(s.t+dt)[0]
    solution = np.append(solution,sol)
    tim = s.t+dt
    time = np.append(time,tim)
    print(s.t+dt, s.integrate(s.t+dt))


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.plot(time,np.abs(solution))
plt.show()
```

Kindest regards,

Catherine

Comment: You should add the error trace so people can determine the problem.

Comment: I have done this but I am not too sure how to format it

Comment: What is the ODE if directly written for a complex-valued function? Something along the lines `z'=-i*coeff*abs(z)^2*z`?

Comment: I will try this now

Comment: If the system is really the components of a complex equation, then something went wrong in determining the real and imaginary parts. If `- coeffr*A[0] + coeffi*A[1]` in the real part is correct, then I would expect `-coeffr*A[1]-coeffi*A[0]` in the imaginary part of the product `-coeff*A`.

Answer (score 0):

You call `.set_f_params(2.0).set_jac_params(2.0)`, but neither `f` nor `jac` have an extra parameter.  Change

```
r.set_initial_value(A0, t0).set_f_params(2.0).set_jac_params(2.0)
```

to just

```
r.set_initial_value(A0, t0)
```

Another problem that you will run into is that your expressions in `f` and `jac` are missing some multiplication signs.  For example, in `f`, the term

```
(A[0]**2 + A[1]**2)(- coeffr*A[0] + coeffi*A[1])
```

should be

```
(A[0]**2 + A[1]**2) * (- coeffr*A[0] + coeffi*A[1])
```

The same problem occurs in the second term, and in several places in `jac`.

Comment: thanks! fixed these things and it is still not doing what I want. Will adjust the code

Answer (score 0):

Taking the first component as likely more correct, and assuming that the system is the real and imaginary part of a complex ODE, I read for that `z'=-c*z*|z|^2`.

Note that the real and imaginary parts are

```
A2*(-coeffr*A[0]+coeffi*A[1]),  A2*(-coeffr*A[1]-coeffi*A[0])
```

note the switched indices in the imaginary part.

Using the new interface `solve_ivp` the whole task can be written much shorter

```py
z0 = 1e-4+0j
coeff = 0.145-0.088j
t0, tf, dt = 0, 100, 0.01

sol = solve_ivp(lambda t,z: -coeff*z*abs(z)**2, [t0,tf], [z0], t_eval=np.arange(t0,tf,dt))

plt.plot(sol.t, abs(sol.y[0]))
```

which indeed gives an almost constant solution, with variations in the range of `1e-11`, which is inside the error tolerances.

Is this reasonable? The equation for the absolute value is

```
d/dt abs(z)^2 = 2*Re(z.conj*dz/dt) = -2*coeffr*abs(z)^4
```

which has a solution

```
abs(z)^2 = abs(z(0))^2/(1+2*coeffr*abs(z(0))^2*t)
```

so that indeed at `t=100` the denominator is `1+2*0.145*1e-8*100=1+2.9e-7` which is very close to 1. The numerical solution is exactly as expected from the exact solution.

Comment: thank you though, I initially wanted to solve it like this but ran into problems

Comment: Now it runs like written. What behavior did you expect from the solution?

Comment: well actually, it was supposed to be a reduced order model the ginzburg-landau equation, but I have a feeling that the parameters in the code in general are awry. Fixing it thusly and will post if I have success.